# Calling AWSCognito signup from lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a lambda function to create a user whenever there is an update in one of the tables of dynamo db.

I have created a dynamodb table with a trigger. I get "adminCreateUser not a function" error when i run the below code in lambda.

```
lambda function:
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    // TODO implement
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response

    });
    context.done(null, 'Hello from Lambda');

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just the code below. Maybe make sure adminCreateUser is in your main AWS SDK, it was only introduced pretty recently.

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
       AWS.config.apiVersions = {
           cognitoidentityserviceprovider: '2016-04-18'
       };
       AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'akid', secretAccessKey: 'secret'});
       var cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
           region: 'us-east-1'
       });
       params = {};
       cognito.adminCreateUser(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
             else     
                 console.log(data); // successful response

       });
context.done(null, 'Hello from Lambda');

    };
```

Comment: Thanks Ionut. Looks like aws-sdk package in inline editor doesn't have this function. I downloaded the latest aws-sdk, created and uploaded a deployment package. It works now.